Client undefined Error in MongoDB Atlas API (Node.js)
export async function getViews(id: string) {
  try {
    await client.connect();
    const collection = client.db("views").collection("views");
    const data = await collection.findOne({id});
    if(!data) {
      return 0;
    }
    return data.views;
  }
  finally {
    await client.close();
  }
}

This is my code. When it runs, it should return the views number of the according document in the collection "views" of the database "views" but instead, it throws a huge number of errors
Here are a few:
MongoExpiredSessionError: Cannot use a session that has ended

MongoTopologyClosedError: Topology is closed

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'close')
    at MongoClient.close (D:\XXXXX\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:260:18)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async addView (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./src/app/posts.ts:56:9)
 ⨯ unhandledRejection: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'close')
    at MongoClient.close (D:\XXXXX\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:260:18)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async addView (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./src/app/posts.ts:56:9)
 ⨯ unhandledRejection: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'close')
    at MongoClient.close (D:\XXXXX\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:260:18)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async addView (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./src/app/posts.ts:56:9)
 ⨯ TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'close')
    at async getViews (./src/app/posts.ts:71:9)
    at async getPostDetails (./src/app/posts.ts:123:24)
    at async Page (./src/app/blog/[id]/page.tsx:31:15)
digest: "486103747"
 ⨯ MongoTopologyClosedError: Topology is closed
    at async getViews (./src/app/posts.ts:63:22)
    at async getPostDetails (./src/app/posts.ts:123:24)
    at async Page (./src/app/blog/[id]/page.tsx:31:15)
digest: "1105313916"
 ⨯ TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'close')
    at async getViews (./src/app/posts.ts:71:9)
    at async getPostDetails (./src/app/posts.ts:123:24)
    at async Page (./src/app/blog/[id]/page.tsx:31:15)
digest: "486103747"
 ⨯ MongoTopologyClosedError: Topology is closed
    at async getViews (./src/app/posts.ts:63:22)
    at async getPostDetails (./src/app/posts.ts:123:24)
    at async Page (./src/app/blog/[id]/page.tsx:31:15)
digest: "1105313916"

BTW I'm using all this in Next.js app.
And everything is loaded in a Server Side rendered component.
I tried doing everything, I checked docs, everything seems correct, but it seems like the connecting to the client and closing the connection seems very hard.
Nothing worked
Please take a look at this and help please.
It's for a blog website I'm making

How is client defined?

You are closing the connection on client in the finally clause and then, presumably, calling the function again or otherwise trying to reuse client. Why? Get rid of the await client.close(); and it'll probably run fine

@devpolo client is defined normally as is given in the Docs

@user20042973 Won't that lead to memory leaks? Isn't it considered best practice to close connections after using them?

I'd recommend looking into 'connection pools'. Establishing and closing connections is expensive. It's fine to close them when you're done with them but it seems like you are trying to reuse it here
